# Are all mathematical theorems necessarily true?

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

Define a formal tautology as a statement where by the nature of its atomic components there exists no truth-value assignment where it is not true. A contingent statement is a statement that is true by facts of the world. A statement is necessarily true if the statement is true in all possible worlds. A necessarily true statement is not contingent and a contingent statement is not necessarily true. A formal tautology is necessarily true. But a necessarily true statement is not always a formal tautology.

Are there mathematical theorems which are contingent? Are all mathematical theorems necessarily true?

Comment: I suspect that in proof theory, "tautology" might have a more restricted and precise meaning than the one you use here. Are you asking about the colloquial use of the word? Sometimes mathematicians say something is "merely a tautology", which might I guess be a misuse of language

Comment: I would say that the question does not make sense as stated. True statements mathematical do not stop being true, so 'always true' is mostly a pleonasm, and 'necessarily true'... well, it would need at least context to become meaningful.

Comment: Define 'necessarily true' as a the statement that is true in all possible worlds (where such a statement could exist). Maybe the questions is rather is all mathematical theorems necessarily true?

Comment: Is the statement "$P$ and not $P$" necessarily true for all statements $P$?

Comment: There is no truth-value assignment for P where P or not P is not true. This is a tautology and necessarily true. But consider a more complex statement, for example the fundamental theorem of algebra. This does not seem to be a formal tautology as there exists truth-value assignments where the statement is false. But surely it seems to be necessarily true. Could the fundamental theorem of algebra be false in a world where it exists?

Comment: Stalyn: asking a bunch of mathematicians will probably not enlighten you on the question of "what is a necessary truth as opposed to a contingent truth?"; it would be much better to ask a local friendly philosophy student, or read Kripke's *Naming and Necessity*, or look on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

Comment: Yes I have read Kripke... I think my question now rephrased makes more sense. It a mathematical question or at least of some mathematical importance.

Comment: I think your question is still a little vague from the strictly mathematical standpoint since it's unclear what the possible worlds might be. I think a reasonable answer to your question is given in Solovay's *Provability interpretations of modal logic* (Israel J. Math 25, 1976). However, I can't convince myself that this answer is correct in all possible worlds...

Comment: Aha yeah I agree possible worlds is still vague. Thank you very much for the article suggestion.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer, because it doesn't answer your rephrased question. So let's assume we are using classical logic. Then regarding the fundamental theorem of algebra, when written formally in for example the first order theory of fields, it has no free variables. So the fact that it follows from whatever axioms you use to fix the complex numbers, is a tautology. The theorem itself is then only a tautology if you give some interpretation to the axioms that will make them "necessarily true". To use your definition, you need to understand all possible worlds. What is possible?

Comment: oh dear! the question changed before I answered it!

Comment: @some guy on the street: it still deserves a +1.

Comment: Stalyn/Paul: I still think that mathoverflow is not the place for this question.  The last I heard, there was no consensus in the philosophical community as to what exactly a "possible world" is, or whether this is even a coherent notion, or whether "necessity" really does mean "true in all possible worlds."  Unless you mean to ask a precise question about first-order modal logic, then you'd be better off asking this question to philosophers.

Comment: Oh very sorry some guy on the street :(  Yeah maybe instead of possible worlds... we can think of them as accessible worlds. For instance a world that is like ours but some of the facts about it are changed. So maybe instead of wearing a blue shirt today I wear a white one. However if "2+2=4" was not true this world would be vastly different and inaccessible (impossible?). This perhaps makes it more clear what contingent and necessary mean. 

Comment: John: Yeah you might be right. However many philosophical problems later became formalized in mathematical language. And surely asking a philosopher this question will only result in more philosophy!

Comment: very odd; a down-voted question with an up-voted answer, and lots of activity... @John Goodrick, the absence withing philosophy of a consensus on "possible worlds" doesn't encourage me to move a question over to the philosophers!  If a question admits a precise interpretation and precise answer within modal logic or model theory, etc., then I think it's a decent mathoverflow question, too.

Comment: @Paul: Perhaps the color of my shirt is necessary? Of course we don't think/believe/hope so, but who knows? It's just easier to imagine a different shirt color than it is to imagine that $2+2\neq 4$, but that could just be a failure of imagination.

Comment: @someguyonthestreet The question is whether or not the present question can be made into a precise one within modal logic or model theory, while still remaining the question which the original poster wanted answered. Formalizing a problem of philosophy in mathematics can have the side effect of defining away the original problem

Comment: @some guy: your answer and François' reference to Solovay shows that there is some connection to mathematics here. But I guess it's going to be closed soon.

Comment: It's funny my original ambiguous question might be considered a simple mathematical question. Yet when I try to be more precise it falls into philosophy. :(

Comment: A sentence of ZF (say), being a sentence of first order logic, has no free variables. So it makes no sense to talk of truth-assignment does it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from the storm of comments, let me just try to answer the question.

There are several ways in a which a mathematical theorem
can be contingent.

- First, the independence phenomenon in set theory shows the striking ubiquity of
  contingency in mathematics. For example, the Continuum Hypothesis is true
  is some set-theoretic
  worlds and false in others (and we can control it
  exactly). There are hundreds of other examples of
  statements with the same independence status---they are
  true in some worlds and false in others. The method of
  forcing has been used to spectacular effect in proving
  many of these independence results.
- The Incompleteness phenomenon of Goedel can be used to show that
  whether a statement is provable or not from a given
  axiom system (in classical logic) can be contingent.
  Specifically, the Incompleteness theorem says that no
  theory T, if consistent, can prove its own consistency.
  Thus, if ZFC is consistent, then there are models of ZFC
  in which ZFC is thought to be inconsistent. In such a
  model, ZFC is thought to prove any statement at all! But
  in our world, not all these statements will be theorems.
  Thus, in this sense, even the question of whether a given statement is a theorem or not
  can be contingent.
- The large cardinal hierarchy in set theory provides
  numerous examples of statements transcending the
  consistency strength of weaker statements. If large cardinals are consistent, then there are some set-theoretical universes in which ZFC proves that there are no inaccessible cardinals and other universes where it does not.

There are also several ways in which contingency is ruled
out.

- First, one of the most important properties of a proof
  system is *soundness*,
  which means that any statement provable in the system from
  true hypotheses will remain true. Of course, this is an
  expected feature of any proof system worthy of the name. A
  *theorem* is a statement having a proof in such a system. Once we have adopted a
  given proof system that is sound, and the axioms are all
  necessarily true, then the theorems will also all be necessarily
  true. In this sense, there can be no contingent theorems.
- Second, one of the profound achievements of Goedel was
  his *Completeness theorem*, which states that any
  statement that holds in all models of a given first order
  theory T, actually has a proof from the theory. For
  example, every statement in the language of group theory
  that happens to be true in all groups, actually has a
  finite proof from the group axioms (using any of several
  proof systems). This is  far from obvious, and I find it profound.
  But it answers a dual version of a question you might
  have asked, which I find interesting, namely:
  Is every necessary truth a theorem?
  The answer is Yes, and this is just what the Completeness
  theorem expresses.

These last two points together explain that if one takes the possible worlds to be all models of a given theory, then the necessary truths are precisely the theorems of that theory.

Comment: Sorry for returning to this after so many years, but what exactly does "is thought to" mean?

Comment: I had meant to express in that sentence the fact that if ZFC is consistent, then there are models of ZFC in which the assertion Con(ZFC) is false.

Answer (score 2):

John Goodrick writes, very much to the point: *The last I heard, there was no consensus in the philosophical community as to what exactly a "possible world" is, or whether this is even a coherent notion, or whether "necessity" really does mean "true in all possible worlds.*  I think this is a problem with how the question is formulated, but if answers do not assume there is a fixed interpetation of these terms, maybe we can say something that is not entirely useless.

Robert Hanna ([Kant's Theory of Judgment, SEP 2009, sect. 2.2.2](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-judgment/#KinProCon)) interprets Kant as saying that "logically possible worlds are nothing but maximal logically consistent sets of concepts".  If we apply this by saying that the logically possible worlds that can contain the concepts as expressed by an axiomatisation are the models of that theory, then it follows that the theorems of an axiomatisation are necessarily true.

There are some issues we might have with this:

1. Necessity on this interpretation is completely orthogonal to questions about what are the appropriate axiomatisations of given mathematical concepts are; and
2. Some mathematical concepts appear to have no adequate axiomatisations.

But necessity has never seemed to be a very useful concept to me as it is put to use in philosophy.  It is one of the concepts that seem to illuminate, but only dazzle.

Answer (score 2):

Charles wrote:

> Robert Hanna (Kant's Theory of Judgment, SEP 2009, sect. 2.2.2) interprets Kant as saying that "logically possible worlds are nothing but maximal logically consistent sets of concepts". If we apply this by saying that the logically possible worlds that can contain the concepts as expressed by an axiomatisation are the models of that theory, then it follows that the theorems of an axiomatisation are necessarily true.

The logical quantifiers interact in odd ways with this idea, and make "maximality" kind of a problematic notion. This is a familiar phenomenon for mathematicians and logicians, of course, but may be worth pointing out explicitly. So, if we have some set of atomic concepts or assertions about the world, then a model of a possible world is a Boolean algebra on this set. Then the basic logical connectives (conjunction, disjunction, negation) can be modelled by intersection, union and complement.

So far, so good. Now, if the set of atomic assertions is finite, then the Boolean algebra is finite, and so it is also a complete lattice, and so quantified statements also have interpretations in the model. But if the set of atomic assertions is not finite, then a Boolean algebra on this set doesn't have to be complete, and so quantified statements might not have interpretations! If we do demand that the Boolean algebra is complete, then what we consider to be "logically possible" depends upon what kinds of logical connectives we wish to consider. (For example, in probability theory the difference between the Kolmogorov and Bayesian axioms of probability is that the Bayesians don't demand countable additivity, which means that an existentially-quantified propositions might not have a Bayesian interpretation.)

Comment: It's quite true that, say, a maximal PA-consistent set of arithmetical formulae need not be omega consistent.  In fact it is cases such as these where we don't have adequate axiomatisations.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the word "tautology" from Mathematical Logic; a logic $L$ means a formal system of deductions $\Sigma \vdash_L \Phi$, satisfying some rules, where $\Sigma$ is a *set of propositions* and $\Phi$ is a *single* proposition.  In this setting, an $L$-tautology is a deduction $\{\} \vdash_L \Phi $; there is a constructive theorem ("Compactness") about classical first-order logic $L_0$ that for every deduction $\Sigma \vdash_{L_0} \Phi$ there is a finite subset $S$ of $\Sigma$ such that $\{\} \vdash \bigwedge S \implies \Phi$; but consider classical first-order logic in the language of arrithmetic and augmented by just the deduction scheme
$$ \{ \Phi[n] | n\in \mathbb{N}\} \vdash \forall n: \Phi[n] .$$
Then this can't be reduced to a tautological implication --- for instance, if $\Phi[n]$ says "$n$ is not the Goedel number of a proof of your favorite Goedel sentence".
Then this logic has a theorem
$$ PA \vdash \forall n:\Phi[n] $$
where $PA$ is is the (infinite) set of axioms for Peano arrithmetic.  But even though first-order arithmetic *can* prove $\Phi[n]$ for all natural $n$, it can't use a single proof to cover all $n$, and in particular, it can't prove the universal generalization.